# :set macmeta breaks # (hash) in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using the following setting in my .vim config files:

```
:set macmeta
```

This fixes the problem with CMD+ALT+ keymaps, but breaks the ALT+3 -> # function. So I cannot type a hash anymore. Any solutions to that?

(OSX 10.8.5 / MacVim VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 Included patches: 1-754)

Thanks.

Comment: I just figured out that I can do :imap <silent> <M-3> # and it works. But not sure if that is a clean way of solving this? Thanks.

Comment: Is not hash a *SHIFT* + 3? If not then how did it happen that ALT + 3 is a hash? I.e. is this a system feature or some other mapping like `imap <A-3> #`?

Comment: Sorry, this is MacBook Pro, UK keyboard: SHIFT+3 is £. About the <M-...> it is alt-key or meta-key in MacVim. Also in MacVim <A-...> is same as <M-...>. The problem is that I still cannot get # when in command mode (:). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: <A- is <M- in every vim instance I heard of. In fact, this is stated at `:h <A-`: “Same as <M-...>”. Though if it is system who transforms `<A-3>` into hash vim should receive this as a hash. I would rather ask this on macvim [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/list), but before test with updated MacVim (latest version is 7.4.052). By the way, if you type `<A-3>` twice in a row, do you get a hash?

Comment: Do you mean in the command line? Type <A-3> twice? No. I get the following error: E488 Trailing characters.

Comment: Anywhere you need to get a hash. Just found a long since fixed bug in macvim issue tracker where somebody complained about having to type `<A-s>` twice to get accented s on some keyboard layout.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting confused here. Probably I need to go and start an "issue" with MacVim. The only thing I need is to get the ALT+CMD+anything working and also being able to get a hash (#) once I hit ALT+3. Thanks.